# This dart code for fetching data from a php page is not working

Tags: flutter, dart

The php page is on 000webhost, it just pulls data from the database and displays it in its raw format, the code for this page is working. Now when I try to fetch this data in flutter and populate a list with it, nothing happens, I've tried several ways already, but non worked. I also checked if the list is actually being displayed in my page by putting data manually, and its working fine.

```
import 'movie.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert' as convert;

List<Movie> newMovies = [];
List<Movie> popMovies = [];

String _baseURL = "000webhosturl";

Future<void> fetchPopMovies(Function(bool success) update) async {
  try {
    final url = Uri.https(_baseURL, 'popMovies.php');
    final response = await http.get(url).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List<dynamic> jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

      for (var jsonMovie in jsonResponse) {
        final movie = Movie(
          name: jsonMovie['name'] ?? '',
          box: jsonMovie['box'] ?? '',
          cover: jsonMovie['cover'] ?? '',
          description: jsonMovie['description'] ?? '',
          platforms: (jsonMovie['platforms'] as List<dynamic>?)
                  ?.map((platform) => platform.toString())
                  .toList() ??
              [],
          rating: (jsonMovie['rating'] as num?)?.toDouble() ?? 0,
          screenshots: (jsonMovie['screenshots'] as List<dynamic>?)
                  ?.map((screenshot) => screenshot.toString())
                  .toList() ??
              [],
        );

        popMovies.add(movie);
      }

      update(true);
    } else {
      update(false);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    update(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: PHP doesn't seem to be related to the question. You verified that `response.statusCode` is 200, and that response is JSON?

Comment: the response is an http response which im converting into json

Comment: The PHP tag brought be here but `convert.jsonDecode` would seem like it requires JSON. `response.statusCode` should be a 200 per your code then the `response.body` should be JSON. If dart/flutter is strict about the return you may need to sent a JSON response header. It's not clear to me where your issue is currently. You should debug these issues to narrow down the issue.